# loadrunner internal server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, loadrunner

I am running a load test with HP Loadrunner 11.52 for a web site which has Asp.Net MVC 5, C#, Razor,WCF (Windows Communication Foundation),WIF (Windows Identity Foundation),Federated Authentication,.Net Framework 4.5,JavaScript, JQuery, JSON, HTML 5,Bootstrap,Telerik Kendo UI,Telerik Reporting,Oracle 11g R2 technologies.

In a simple search senario, when I click search button, it calls an ajax function "Ara" as following.

```
web_custom_request("Ara", 
        "URL=http://egitim.gocnet.gov.tr/Kisi/Ara/**Ara**", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=application/json", 
        "Referer=http://egitim.gocnet.gov.tr/Kisi/Ara", 
        "Snapshot=t8.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        "EncType=application/json; charset=UTF-8", 
        "Body={\"success\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"result\":{\"mod\":\"kimlikBilgileri\",\"kimlikNo\":null,\"ad\":{\"aranacakString\":\"joe\",\"aramaKriterTipi\":1},\"soyad\":{\"aranacakString\":\"halley\",\"aramaKriterTipi\":1},\"babaAd\":{\"aranacakString\":\"robert\",\"aramaKriterTipi\":1},\"anneAd\":{\"aranacakString\":null,\"aramaKriterTipi\":1},\"dogumTarih\":{\"gun\":null,\"ay\":null,\"yil\":null},\"uyruk\":null,\"ikametIzinNo\":null,\"pasaportNo\":null,\"uyrukKimlikNo\":null,\"pageSize\":10,\"page\":1,\"total\":0,\"sortFields\":null}}", 
        LAST);
```

When I replay this scenario it gives the following error:

> Action.c(113): Error -26612: HTTP Status-Code=500 (Internal Server Error) for "http://egitim.gocnet.gov.tr/Kisi/Ara/Ara" [MsgId: MERR-26612]

What can be its reason?

Comment: It's a server error, so check your server's log.

Comment: I learned that Web 2.0 licence does not support Asp.net MVC 5 so it can be reason.

Comment: @SinemKırtaç you have a server issue not related to LoadRunner. As far as I know, MVC 5 uses regular HTTP calls, perhaps you need special DFE for it but from your code I don't even think this is needed. Please make sure you are authorized to make that REST call, maybe you need some sort of authentication or other type of authorization.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 in a loadrunner result generally means that you have provided the server with incorrect information or an incorrect request based upon the state of the server.   If you are not explicitly checking for valid expected results from each and every one of your prior requests and simply relying upon an HTTP 200 status to ensure "success!" then then odds are high that you have received a valid HTTP 200 response but with invalid data for continuing the business process.

Check your request responses and branch your code when you have an unexpected response.